# How to use Devel::Cover for application built from xsp (abc.xsp) files

Tags: perl, testing, code-coverage

I have a web application running on apache. That application using xsp extension file to invoke the application on browser and that xsp file using perl code inside, for example...

abc.xsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsp:page
  xmlns:xsp="http://apache.org/xsp/core/w1"
>
<xsp:logic>
use Data::Dumper;
</xsp:logic>
<test>
    <xsp:logic>
        my $u= $r->pnotes('tester');
        die "must be admin to view this page" unless $r->pnotes('q')->{pp};

    </xsp:logic>
</test>
</xsp:page>
```

So i want to to get Code coverage on this by using Devel::Cover module. Generally for single file we use

> perl -MDevel::Cover filename.pl

but for xsp base application where it is calling multiple xsp file, how we can do coverage.
Pls suggest.